# Django Let Users Add Custom Domains

Tags: python, django, dns

I would like to allow users to map their domain to their page in my Django app. So if their page is at: user.mydomain.com, I'd like them to be able to map their domain to the url so it becomes: usersdomain.com .

I found this answer which gave me an idea of how to setup subdomains:

> If you control the nameserver for the domain and have access to the
>   RNDC Key, you can use the post-signup view/signal to squirt out a
>   cname to your DNS server that will resove username.yoursite.com to
>   yoursite.com. Make sure apache is set up to recieve a wildcard
>   virtualhost to the correct app, and then use a custom middleware to
>   read request.META['SERVER_NAME'].lsplit('.')[0] to see what the
>   subdomain is. You can then use this information in your views to
>   differentiate user subdomains.

But I'm at a loss as to how to let users point their domains to my subdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I would approach this is first, instruct your users to set up the appropriate DNS record to point their domain to yours (likely a CNAME).

Then you'll need to set the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting in your `settings.py` to a wildcard (*), which is supported. The thing to be aware of is this configuration opens a security vulnerability, so you'll want to implement your own host validation, [recommended at the middleware level](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) by Django.

Then you'll have to modify whatever technique you're using to display a user's page. Instead of matching the subdomain, match the entire domain.